# How to open pdf with jump to particular page in Adobe Embed Api?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, embed

I implemented the adobe embed api in Angular using Angular sample, now I want to jump to a particular page

Example: I opened example.pdf it has 14 pages and I want to jump to the 3rd page, how can I do that.

In this https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDFOpenParameters.pdf , I saw the property of page which we can add after pdf URL like example.pdf#page=3 so it will directly jump to 3rd page of that pdf.

But when I implement that property it won't jump to that page

Any suggestions for this are appreciated, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally able to jump to a particular page using the goToLocation function in adobe embed api.

For reference please check, https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/docs.html?view=view

```
const previewFilePromise = this.pdfRef = this.adobeDCView.previewFile({

 content: {

   location: {
     url: fileName, 

    }

  },

 metaData: {

   fileName: 'my file.pdf',

   id: "filed"

 }

},viewerConfig);

previewFilePromise.then((adobeViewer:any) => {

   adobeViewer.getAPIs().then((apis:any) => {
     apis.gotoLocation(<Page_Number>, <X_Coordinate>, <Y_Coordinate>)
        .then(() => console.log("Success"))

        .catch((error:any) => console.log(error));
    });

})
```

X and Y coordinates are optional, so using this function we can go to any page inside iframe using our own custom button